# Touch point in various screen sizes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This question is related to [Get Touch Coordinates Relative To A Custom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522914/get-touch-coordinates-relative-to-a-custom-imageview/38525259#38525259)

I'm developing an android app and I have a problem with touch coordinate points.
Code from linked thread is working but only in one screen size. When I add a point on a 5.5" screen device and read it on a 9" screen device, it appears in a different position relative to the image on which I'm drawing. The image size is the same on both devices.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public class DrawViewInside : ImageView
```

{

```
public static Bitmap bitmapInside;
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Point point = new Point();

private Canvas mCanvas;
private static Bitmap mutableBitmap;
private Context mContext;
public static Bitmap b;
public void SetCarId(int id)
{
    carId = id;
}
public DrawViewInside(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
{
    mContext = context;
    setDefault(drawable);
}

public void SetBitmap(int drawableId)
{
    setDefault(drawableId);
    Invalidate();
}


protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width;

    var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    if (b != null)
    {
        SetMeasuredDimension(b.Width, b.Height);
    }

}


public async void setDefault(int drawableId)
{


        BitmapFactory.Options options = await GetBitmapOptionsOfImage(drawableId);
        paint.Color = Color.Red;
        paint.StrokeWidth = 15;
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        var widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);
        var heightInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels);

        b = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, drawableId);esources, drawableId);
        mutableBitmap = b.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        mCanvas.Save();

}


protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    DrawCircle(canvas);


}
private void DrawCircle(Canvas canvas)
{
    if (mCanvas == null)
    {
        setDefault(drawable);
    }
    else
    {
        mCanvas.Restore();
        mCanvas.DrawCircle(point.x, point.y, 10, paint);
        mCanvas.Save();
        canvas.DrawBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        bitmapInside = mutableBitmap;
    }


}

public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:

            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    Activity act = (Activity)mContext;

                   float viewX = e.RawX;// - this.Left;
                    float viewY = e.RawY;// - this.Top;
                    int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
                    this.GetLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
                    point.x = viewX - viewCoords[0];// e.RawX;
                    point.y = viewY - viewCoords[1];// e.RawY;

                break;
            }
    Invalidate();
    return true;

}

}
public class Point
{
    public float x, y;
}
```

What I want achieve:
I'm drawing a dot where I touch the screen (while displaying an image). The dot draws correctly, and I send the coordinates of this dot to the a web service. When I reopen this activity, the old dots are drawn correctly on top of the image. It works perfectly on the same resolution/screen size but when I try load points from  5.5", 1920x1080p screen on an 8", 1200x800p screen, for example, the dots are drawn in a different location relative to image on the screen (bitmap).

How can I draw the dots on the same location relative to the image in devices with different screen sizes and resolutions?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you using java or c#?

Comment: Sorry about that. Im using c# Xamarin but answers in Java are still acceptable, because I can easily port to c# (Android and Xamarin Android is pretty the same)

Comment: Could you add a little more detail including the code you're using, the result you're seeing, and the desired result? It sounds like you're drawing on an image and need to load the drawing on multiple screen sizes, but I don't fully understand.

Comment: @dylansturg  I added  some info.

Comment: Improved wording and clarity.

Comment: It seems that you are saving the coordinates in pixels, which will surely cause the issue you are experiencing. Have you tried converting those to `dp` instead? It will certainly be more complex that a straight through conversion using `TypedValue.applyDimension(...)` since you'll need to take the image size and zoom level into consideration.